# Does any IQP functionality need to be explicitly enabled in SQL 2022?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2022

I'm exploring IQP functionality on SQL 2022 Developer Edition. It appears based on documentation that enabling Query Store is the only requirement for some of the IQP functionalities, and that Query Store and all IQP features are enabled by default.

#### Questions

1. Is this true for only new dbs or even dbs that are migrated from an older SQL version?

   - For example the automatic plan choice correction feature needs to be explicitly enabled:

     ```
       ALTER DATABASE <yourDatabase>
       SET AUTOMATIC_TUNING ( FORCE_LAST_GOOD_PLAN = ON );
     ```
   - Another example that needs explicit enabling is `DOP_FEEDBACK`.
2. Does any other IQP functionality need to be explicitly enabled in SQL 2022?

Answer (score 4):

Apart from [Degree of parallelism (DOP) feedback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/intelligent-query-processing-feedback?view=sql-server-ver16#degree-of-parallelism-dop-feedback), which is [disabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-scoped-configuration-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#dop_feedback---on--off-) by default, all other IQP features are enabled "out of the box", provided that the database has a compatibility level equal to or higher than the compatibility level where the feature was first introduced.
[image]
As you mentioned, [some features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/intelligent-query-processing?view=sql-server-ver16#query-store-requirement) also require Query Store to be enabled and in READ_WRITE mode.

Comment: How about parameter sensitive plan optimization?

Comment: And is this true for new dbs or even the migrated dbs?

Comment: Parameter sensitive plan optimization is ON by default starting in database compatibility level 160 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-scoped-configuration-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#parameter_sensitive_plan_optimization---on--off-).